# How to form dynamic rows and sections in UITableView based on response from webservice

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am able to fetch response from web services,which am storing in an array.This array has to be separated to sections and rows of UITableview.In response from webservice announcements having same ComputedDate should be as section title and announcement title has to be rows of that section based on computedDate.I am able to form haeders but my issue is all rows are common for all sections. o/p in UITableView should be:

```
June 21,2014
Performance and Load
June 20,2014
My teest
Sample
June 19,2014
All samp
June 18,2014
qwerty
```

The response format is:

```
{ "ResultSet1": [
    {
        "AnnouncementId": 3,
        "AnnouncementTitle": "Performance and Load",
        "AnnouncementPostedTime": "21 Jun,2014,11:07 AM",
        "ComputedDate": "Jun 21,2014",
    },{
        "AnnouncementId": 22,
        "AnnouncementTitle": "My teest",
        "AnnouncementPostedTime": "20 Jun,2014,10:11 AM",
        "ComputedDate": "Jun 20,2014",

    }, {
        "AnnouncementId": 21,
        "AnnouncementTitle": "Sample",
        "AnnouncementPostedTime": "20 Jun,2014,10:11 AM",
        "ComputedDate": "Jun 20,2014",

    },
    {
        "AnnouncementId": 20,
        "AnnouncementTitle": "All samp",
        "AnnouncementPostedTime": "19 Jun,2014,10:11 AM",
        "ComputedDate": "Jun 19,2014",

    }, {
        "AnnouncementId": 19,
        "AnnouncementTitle": "qwerty",
        "AnnouncementPostedTime": "18 Jun,2014,10:10 AM",
        "ComputedDate": "Jun 18,2014",

    }

]
}
```

My code isbelow:

```
   arrResult=[dict valueForKey:@"ResultSet1"];

    listOfObjects = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSDictionary *dictResSub in arrResult)
    {
        Announcements *at = [[Announcements alloc] init];
        at.announcementTitle = [dictResSub valueForKey:@"AnnouncementTitle"];
        at.announcementPostedTime = [dictResSub valueForKey:@"AnnouncementPostedTime"];
        at.computedDate=[dictResSub valueForKey:@"ComputedDate"];

        [listOfObjects addObject:at];
    }

    int i;

    for (i=0 ;i< [listOfObjects count];i++){

        Announcements *atAnnouncement1p1;
        NSString *str1p1;
        Announcements *atAnnouncement1=[listOfObjects objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *str1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",atAnnouncement1.computedDate];
        if (i==0) {
            [arrHeaders addObject:str1];
            [arrFirstObj addObject:atAnnouncement1];

        }



        if (i<[listOfObjects count]-1) {
        atAnnouncement1p1=[listOfObjects objectAtIndex:i+1];
        str1p1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",atAnnouncement1p1.computedDate];
            if ([str1 isEqualToString:str1p1]) {

                NSLog(@"Already there");
                [arrFirstObj addObject:atAnnouncement1p1];

            }
            else{
                [arrHeaders addObject:str1p1];

            }

        }

    }
}
//    [tableVwCategories reloadData];

tableVwCategories.frame=CGRectMake(0, 70, 320, 300);
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
return [arrHeaders count];
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [arrHeaders objectAtIndex:section];

}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [arrFirstObj count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier=@"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];
}

Announcements *at = [arrFirstObj objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Cell.textLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",at.announcementTitle];
cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
return cell;
}
```

Comment: how to separate data into rows and section of UITableview

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the current code isn't completely clear to me as I don't know what doesn't happen what should happen or vice versa. So I'm still guessing a bit. But I see you are not implementing [viewForHeaderInSection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aviewForHeaderInSection%3a) which is what I would use to implement custom headers. Also I think you need [heightForHeaderInSection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForHeaderInSection%3a) set to something different than 0 (obviously).

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Simple on the fly generated UIView, you could also return your own subclass of UIView
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 18)];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, tableView.frame.size.width, 18)];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
    label.text = [arrHeaders objectAtIndex:section];

    return view;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
    // Should be same as UIView that you return in previous function
    return 18.0f;
}
```

Comment: output should be in above format.I have issue in separating obtained dat to sections and rows

Comment: OK I will use another answer to get into that.

Answer (score 0):

OK so you want to nest your data. I would suggest a custom class to store your data something likes this:

.h:

```
@interface AnnouncementGroup : NSObject

@property NSString *computedDate;
@property NSMutableArray* announcements;

- (id)initWithComputedDate:(NSString *)computedDate;

@end
```

.m:

```
#import "AnnouncementGroup.h"
@implementation AnnouncementGroup

- (id)initWithComputedDate:(NSString *)computedDate;
{
    self = [super init];

    self.announcements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.computedDate = computedDate;

    return self;
}

@end
```

Then we need to loop over your data and sort it right:

```
// Where you want to start processing
NSMutableArray *announcementGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *announcementResult in arrResult)
{
    AnnouncementGroup *group = [ThisClassName newOrExistingAnnouncementGroupForComputedDate:computedDate searchInList:announcementGroups];

    Announcement *at = [[Announcement alloc] init];
    at.announcementTitle = [dictResSub valueForKey:@"AnnouncementTitle"];
    at.announcementPostedTime = [dictResSub valueForKey:@"AnnouncementPostedTime"];
    at.computedDate = [dictResSub valueForKey:@"ComputedDate"];

    [group.announcements addObject:at];
}

// Static function on same object, will return a new group if the computedDate is not in the list
+ (AnnouncementGroup *)newOrExistingAnnouncementGroupForComputedDate:(NSString *)computedDate searchInList:(NSArray *)announcementGroups;
{
    for (AnnouncementGroup *group in announcementGroups)
    {
        if ([group.computedDate equals:computedDate])
        {
            return group;
        }
    }

    AnnouncementGroup newGroup = [[AnnouncementGroup alloc] initWithComputedDate:computedDate];
    [announcementGroups addObject:newGroup];

    return newGroup;
}
```

As you see this code will create a new group for a given date and add it to the list with groups, unless the date is already used for a group, then it will return the existing group. In both cases, the announcement will be added to that AnnouncementGroup object. Now you have a datamodel that is nested properly.

Now some functions in your implementation of the UITableView:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return announcementGroups.count;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    AnnouncementGroup group = (AnnouncementGroup *) [announcementGroups objectAtIndex:section];
    return group.computedDate;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    AnnouncementGroup group = (AnnouncementGroup *) [announcementGroups objectAtIndex:section];
    return group.announcements.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];
    }

    AnnouncementGroup *group = [announcementGroups objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    Announcement *announcement = [group objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",announcement.announcementTitle];
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    return cell;
}
```

As you see this requires some more casting but I think that only will make your code more clean and more maintainable.